# Getting the error ControlPlaneProvisioningInternalError while creating the kubernetes cluster in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-aks

while i am trying to deploy the kubernetes cluster in azure, getting the error like, `message: DeploymentFailed.The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed' and code:ControlPlaneProvisioningInternalError`

Could anybody suggest me,how to resolve this issue?

Comment: As I know, there are two possible reasons. One is your quota is limited for creating more resources, such as CPU. Another is that the region is not available for AKS currently. You can try to change the region.

Answer (score 0):

Just retry it, its a platform error, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Hello 4c74356b41. I tried number of times to create a kubernetes cluster in Azure with different regions. I am unable to get the `view dashboard` option in my cluster.

Comment: well, does the cluster provision fail with some errors other than this? does this error still happen?

Comment: yes, still i getting the same error. What might be error?

Comment: i this case I'd suggest you specify how exactly are you deploying it?

Comment: previously i could create cluster successfully many times with new resource group everytime. now also i am doing the same thing, deploying the kubernetes cluster through Azure Portal. but this same i getting this issue.

Comment: oh, it doesnt work using the portal, can you find the error from the `MC_*` resource group deployments?

Comment: i am not sure on that. but getting the error like this `message: DeploymentFailed.The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed' and code:ControlPlaneProvisioningInternalError`. while i am trying to see the insights, it shows no  data for selected filters for every resources.